# React-konva: place elements of a Group with absolute (stage) coordinates

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I started using React-Konva just 1 week ago, but I have a problem in what I am doing and I can't figure it out, due my lack of knowledge of Konva.

I have a`Stage`, with `Layer` and `Group` inside.
Inside the `Group` I have a `Rect` and  some data from an api that places some `Image` on the screen.
Actually I can move the `Group`, and I want that when I move it, all elements inside it move together, which actually works great.

I can resize the `Rect`, and what I am trying to do is to place the `Image` elements with absolute `x,y` (of the stage), instead I don't know why, the images are placed on the stage taking into account the coordinates of the `Rect/Group`.

Is there a way to place the images (inside the group) using the stage area coordinates instead of the `Rect/Group` coordinates.
Actually when I resize the `Rect`, saving `width, height,x and y` to backend, and then reload or re-enter the page, I see that the `Rect` is resized correctly, but all the `Image` elements are shifted from left because their `x, y` are relative to `Rect/Group` and not the `Stage`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape's position is relative to their container element.  In your case the rect and image have the group as the container, and the group has the layer as the container.

Once a shape is added to a group, the shape's position is relative to the group's position.

If you want to set the image shape position relative to the stage use

`image.absolutePosition({x: newStageX, y: newStageY}).`

If you want to get the position relative to the stage use

`absPos = shape.absolutePosition().`

There is also a 'node.getAbsolutePosition()' method that can take an ancestor node to give the position relative to that ancestor, but there is no equiv setter method.  Not sure how to apply that in React but that's what you need to do.